# Помогите вивести категории (yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

Модель Portfolio с гетером:

```
public static function tableName(){
    return 'portfolio';
}

public function getCategory() {
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

в index вивожу категории отлично:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'name',
        'description',
        [
            'attribute' => 'category_id',
            'value' => function($date) {
                return $date->category->name;  // тут виводятса просто супер
            }
        ],
       ...
```

Подскажите пожалуйсто как мне реализовать добавление нового портфолио чтоб гетером достать список названий всех категорій в методе CREATE??

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList( что тут? ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownList(\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'name')) ?>
```